# Duplicate tags [spring-jpa] should be [spring-data-jpa]

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

I created a [synonym request](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/spring-data-jpa/synonyms) and would appreciate upvotes if you agree.

I also accidentally created a synonym request for [spring-data] and it seems the only way to get rid of it if some people downvote it.

Once the synonym is in place one should change the old tagged questions, right?

Update:

There actually to possible replacements for [spring-data].

Part of the questions should really be tagged [spring-orm] because they relate to JPA features in the Spring Framework itself.

Most should be retagged with [spring-data-jpa].

Comment: Is the title backwards or the synonym proposal?

Comment: I've removed the proposed `spring-data` synonym... but like @Hans says - have you got this the right way around?

Comment: @Hans Passant I'm not sure. I found the description on the page and the FAQ rather confusing. The intention is to have spring-data-jpa as the proper tag.

Comment: @JonClements see previous comment.